# Oozie Java Action Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, oozie

I am trying to run a oozie workflow for java action. My Java code can read a Word file from HDFS and write backs CSV files on HDFS.
My workflow.xml contains -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4" name="Word-Processing">
<start to="PathologyReport-Processing"/>
<action name="PathologyReport-Processing">
<java>
  <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
  <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
 <configuration>
  <property>
   <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
   <value>${queueName}</value>
  </property>
  <property>
   <name>oozie.libpath</name>
   <value>${JarPath}</value>
  </property>
 </configuration>
 <main-class>${MainClass}</main-class>
 <arg>-libjars</arg>
 <arg>${JarPath}</arg>
 <arg>${in}</arg>
 <arg>${out}</arg>
</java>
<ok to="end"/>
<error to="fail"/>
</action>
<kill name="fail">
<message>Java Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

My job.properties contains following code

```
nameNode=hdfs://CTSC00385700501:8020
jobTracker=CTSC00385700501:8032
workflowRoot=PathologyReport
queueName=default
MainClass=SampleUnstructured
JarPath=hdfs://localhost:8020/user/oozie/${workflowRoot}/lib/poi-3.9.jar
in=hdfs://localhost:8020/user/oozie/${workflowRoot}/SampleWord.docx
out=hdfs://localhost:8020/user/oozie/${workflowRoot}/output
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath=hdfs://localhost:8020/user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20150513153121/
oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://localhost:8020/user/oozie/${workflowRoot}
```

I have specified the path for Apache POI jar file still it is not able to locate it. Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

can u check the job.property configuration you have mention.
as i know the "`${workflowRoot}`" parameter should be mentnion in the workflow.xml and job.xml should be defined as the

```
<property> 
<name>workflowRoot</name>
<value>${workflowRoot}</value> 
</property>
```

then try to run the oozie job, belive these will work smoth.

Answer (score 0):

From [Oozie MapReduce cookbook](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OOZIE/Map+Reduce+Cookbook):

> ...Please note that the -libjars option supported by the Hadoop
>   command-line is not supported by Oozie...

With Oozie, you should instead add a **<file>** element in the Action to reference the JAR-to-be-downloaded-automagically-in-the-working-dir-of-the-YARN-container-at-run-time.